# Should I add a boolean field into index to decrease the Examined:Returned Ratio in MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have an `updateMany` operation in which the query part is just are two fields, one a simple text field and the other a boolean field. Text field is indexed and the index is used properly in the query and everything is working. The only problem is that Examined:Returned Ratio is to high (aprox 6000) and I was wondering if adding the boolean field to index would improve the Ratio. I think so, and my next question is if should I do this or not, because I have read that boolean fields should not be indexed (as a regular rule). Performance is not an issue currently.

Query is the following:

```
updateMany({textField: "value", isField: true}. {$set: {isField: false}} )
```

The current index is: `{textField: 1}`

Comment: Of course you should do it.  How else will you test to see if it performs better?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `explain()` function on this query, you will see that mongodb actually needs to go and scan the collection in order to find these records since you havent indexed all the fields used in the query.

This should be a compound index.

```
db.{collectionName}.createIndex({textField: 1, isField: 1});
```

Comment: I checked my query with explain using `.find()` and single field index `{textField: 1}` is being used, so not COLLSCAN is happening.